# Comparar indice ao iten digitado!

Tags: javascript

Comecei a estudar javascript, e estou em um exercicio que fiquei perdida!
Alguem pode me ajudar? Travei nesse exercicio e não achei nenhuma referencia.

Segue enunciado:
Ao premir o botão, será pedido ao utilizador (através de prompt()) que indique o número do primeiro prato e uma segunda
mensagem para indicar o número do segundo prato.
Vamos criar um programa que se encarregará de fazer corresponder o número à descrição do prato.
Mostrar com um alert() a que prato as opções escolhidas correspondem com uma mensagem semelhante a esta: "Escolheu
como primeiro prato Salada Mista e como segundo prato Macarrão com Pesto".

Javascript:

```
function escolher(opcao1, opcao2){

opcao1 = document.querySelector(`button`)
opcao1 = prompt(`Informe o numero do Primeiro prato`)
opcao1 = eval(opcao1)

opcao2 = document.querySelector(`button`)
opcao2 = prompt(`Informe o numero do Segundo prato`)
opcao2 = eval(opcao2)
}
```

Html:

```
<ol id="menu">
    <li value="1">Lasanha</li>
    <li value="2">Feijão Tropeiro</li>
    <li value="3">Yakisoba</li>
    <li value="4">Strogonoff de Carne</li>
    <li value="5">Risoto de Camarão</li>
    <li value="6">Feijoada</li>
    <li value="7">Nhoque Bolonhesa</li>
    <li value="8">Leitão a pururuca</li>
    <li value="9">Virado a Paulista</li>
    <li value="10">Paella</li>
</ol>

<button onclick="escolher()">Escolher Menu</button>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

O exercício proposto envolve a criação de um programa em JavaScript que associa números a pratos de um menu e exibe uma mensagem com os pratos escolhidos pelo usuário.

Há alguns erros no código fornecido que precisam ser corrigidos. Vou apresentar uma solução modificada que atende ao enunciado:

```js
function escolher() {
  var opcao1 = prompt("Informe o número do primeiro prato");
  var opcao2 = prompt("Informe o número do segundo prato");
  
  var pratos = document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("li");
  
  var descricaoOpcao1 = pratos[opcao1 - 1].innerText;
  var descricaoOpcao2 = pratos[opcao2 - 1].innerText;
  
  var mensagem = "Escolheu como primeiro prato " + descricaoOpcao1 + " e como segundo prato " + descricaoOpcao2;
  alert(mensagem);
}
```

Nessa solução, a função `escolher()` é chamada quando o botão é clicado. No início da função, usamos a função `prompt()` para solicitar ao usuário os números dos pratos. Armazenamos esses valores nas variáveis `opcao1` e `opcao2`.

Em seguida, obtemos todos os elementos `li` dentro da lista com o id "menu" usando a função `getElementById` em conjunto com `getElementsByTagName`. Essa função retorna uma lista de elementos, e podemos acessá-los por índice.

Usamos os números fornecidos pelo usuário para acessar o elemento correspondente na lista de pratos (`pratos[opcao1 - 1]` e `pratos[opcao2 - 1]`). Subtraímos 1 dos números fornecidos, pois os índices de uma lista começam em 0, enquanto os valores dos atributos `value` na lista começam em 1.

Por fim, concatenamos as descrições dos pratos escolhidos na mensagem de alerta e exibimos a mensagem ao usuário.

No HTML fornecido, você pode deixar o botão como está:

```html
<button onclick="escolher()">Escolher Menu</button>
```

Espero que isso ajude você a avançar com o exercício! Se você tiver mais dúvidas, por favor, me avise.

Answer (score -3):

Olá,

O exercício pediu que você realizasse esta lógica utilizando o 'prompt' e acredito que por este motivo você ficou em dúvidas, pois você acabou utilizando elementos HTML.

Quando estamos utilizando o prompt do navegador não precisamos de tags HTML para realizar a lógica do script.

Segue abaixo o que você precisa:

obs: lembre-se de criar um arquivo com o nome index.html

```
<script>
    
    let primeiroPrato = 0
    let pratos = [] //vai armazenar em ordem os pratos

    do {

        primeiroPrato = Number(prompt(
            `
            Escolha a opção para o primeiro prato:

            1 - Salada Mista
            2 - Macarrão com Pesto`
            
        ))

        if(primeiroPrato == 1){
            alert(`Primeiro prato: Salada Mista`)
            pratos.push('Salada Mista') //armazenará o prato na posição zero do array

        } else if(primeiroPrato == 2){
            alert(`Primeiro prato: Macarrão com Pesto`)
            pratos.push('Macarrão com Pesto') //armazenará o prato na posição zero do array

        } else{
            alert(`Operação inválida! Tente novamente`)
        }    
    } while (primeiroPrato != 1 && primeiroPrato != 2);

    let segundoPrato = 0

    do {
        segundoPrato = Number(prompt(
            `
            Escolha a opção para o segundo prato:

            1 - Salada Mista
            2 - Macarrão com Pesto`
        ))

        if(segundoPrato == 1){
            alert(`Segundo prato: Salada Mista`)
            pratos.push('Salada Mista') //armazenará o prato na posição 1 do array

        } else if(segundoPrato == 2){
            alert(`Segundo prato: Macarrão com Pesto`)
            pratos.push('Macarrão com Pesto') //armazenará o prato na posição 1 do array

        } else{
            alert(`Operação inválida! tente novamente.`)
        }

    } while (segundoPrato != 1 && segundoPrato != 2);

    alert(`Escolheu como primeiro prato ${[pratos[0]]} e como segundo prato ${[pratos[1]]}`)
    
</script>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).